# React Native with Stack Navigation

Tags: javascript, html

I created stack navigation successfully, but after some days it doesn't work :(
I run in the cmd:

```
npm install --save react-navigation
npm install --save react-native-gesture-handler
react-native link
npm install
```

but get the following errors: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjSkV.png)

Comment: Hi. If you provide more information some at this site might be able to help you. So try to include any error message, webserver, and settings that relates to your issue. Regards

Comment: I recommend to actually heed guides like [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and prompts like `enter image description here` - who is going to follow a link just to have a look at a nondescript image?

Comment: hi, I've fixed code formatting in your post, but the last line look incomplete, could you fix it? If you really need an answer, I'd suggest to a) insert error messages as text beside your screenshot and b) provide the code that gives the error! Without it, we can only wild-guess the problem and hardly propose a fix. See also [mcve]

Comment: react native link often cause same issue, read https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios
And do manual link.

Comment: Try removing node_modules and run npm install again. Sometimes restarting the system also helps which tends to remove the cache.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are useing react-native-navigation v2 or you forgot to import createApp container.

I recommend you to execute below commands
rm -rf node_modules; watchman watch-del-all; npm i;
and do "Erase all contents and settings" in your simulator.